# Python while loop ( doesnt comes out from while loop )

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-3.6

I want this python code comes out from loop when I enter 0 as **input** number of "num" variable But it continues printing these three lines constantly

---

Thanks

```
num = 10     #10 is dummy number for starting loop 
while(num!=0):
    print("1)Test func1")
    print("2)Test func2")
    print("0)Exit")
    num = input("Enter a number:")

print("Comes out from while loop!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There reason behind is that the input takes input as a string and you have to either convert it to int:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
```

or change the while loop:

```
while(num!='0'):
```

Comment: While your code snippet is correct, its best to provide at least some explanation to accompany it.

Comment: @ Dillon Davis , implemented, thanks!

Comment: Thanks .. It works properly ;)

Comment: @Mohammad_B_Shirdareh, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check on the left side of the answer, it will remove the question from the question queue and distribute the points around, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

print takes input as string , in order to come out of loop
use 
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))

it will consider num variable as an integer but not an string and will come out of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You have got a correct answer before this but you can change your code too:

```
while True:
    print("1)Test func1")
    print("2)Test func2")
    print("0)Exit")
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    if num == '0':
        break

print("Comes out from while loop!")
```

at the begining while always get True, you don't need to set value, 'break' means 'stop current loop and exit'